# LDAP saturating the bandwidth

Tags: ldap

As per object we are experiencing LDAP peaks that are saturating our corporate wan connection.
From a trace analyzed I can say that most of the traffic is generated from two list in the Partial Attribute Set:
Basically what happens is that the clients in our branch offices are making NeyLOGON queries to the DCs in the HeadQuarter and immediately after thay ask for this LDAP objectclass=*; now the answer that comes back is a list of all the RODCs deployed worldwide and for every RODC there is a PartialAtributeList....in particular the msDS-RevealedUsers and msDS-AuthenticatedToAccountList contains a bunch of users.

Can you please help me out?

```
LDAPMessage searchRequest(1) "<ROOT>" baseObject
...
Filter: (objectclass=*)  <-- this is the request with some attributes
attributes: 15 items
AttributeDescription: subschemaSubentry
AttributeDescription: dsServiceName
AttributeDescription: namingContexts
AttributeDescription: defaultNamingContext
AttributeDescription: schemaNamingContext
AttributeDescription: configurationNamingContext
AttributeDescription: rootDomainNamingContext
AttributeDescription: supportedControl
AttributeDescription: supportedLDAPVersion
AttributeDescription: supportedLDAPPolicies
AttributeDescription: supportedSASLMechanisms
AttributeDescription: dnsHostName
AttributeDescription: ldapServiceName
AttributeDescription: serverName
AttributeDescription: supportedCapabilities

Then the answer comes for every RODC like this:
PartialAttributeList item objectClass
PartialAttributeList item cn
....
PartialAttributeList item msDS-RevealedUsers
....
PartialAttributeList item msDS-AuthenticatedToAccountlist
PartialAttributeList item msDS-AuthenticatedToAccountlist;range=0-1499
....
```

where the mentioned lists are huge

Comment: 'They ask for this LDAP objectclass=*' This of course is the problem. Why are they doing that?

Comment: I don't know :) ...if i knew the problem would be solved....but i can tell you the other attributes aren't that big....instead the msDS-RevealedUsers and msDS-AuthenticatedToAccountList are huge!! is there a way to tune up the attributes sent by the DCs??

Comment: There is a way to limit the number of search results returned. It is often set to 1000. I think I would do that, or set it even lower, just to deliberately break pathological cases like this so you can find where they originate. See the documentation for slapd.conf.

Comment: [I am here unjustifiably assuming you're using OpenLDAP.]